# How to click an html box without registering the click event of the box behind it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have one box placed on top of another box both having their own separate click events. The box on top is blue and the one behind it is red. Whenever I click on the blue box the red box's click event also registers. Here's the code. Also please do not use event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); if you're answering as it has given me trouble in the past.

```js
box1() {
  console.log("box 1");   
}
box2() {
  console.log("box 2");
}
```

```css
.box1{
    left : 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;

}
.box2{
    position: relative;
    left : 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1" (click)="box1()">
        <div class="box2" (click)="box2()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Thank you @AldinBradaric for answering. But, i had issues with using this method. I have attached an article related to this issue.https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: Any issues in particular? As the article mentions, keeping track of where you're using `stopPropagation` is important but in your particular use case, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: This is an example question I've posted in the one i'm working  when i use the `stopPropagation` on some events it's not getting me the data i wanted.

Comment: You could perhaps try to reassign the click events to different HTML components, e.g. buttons. Anyhow, it would be easier to analyze your issue if you posted more detailed code.

Comment: I'' try that. Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reviewed your code and i have changed your css & html little bit and it works like a charm.

box.html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box1" (click)="box1()"></div>
   <div class="box2" (click)="box2()"></div>
</div>
```

box.css

```
.box1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
}
.box2 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 999;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

box.ts

```
 box1() {
    console.log("box 1");   
  }
  box2() {
    console.log("box 2");
  }
```

working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rxyqcd?file=src/app/app.component.ts